# Force Portrait Screen Rotation in MS Remote Desktop App

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, remote-access, orientation

I'm using Microsoft's Remote Desktop Client v8.0.11.25133 to connect to a Windows Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Session Host (Terminal) Server.  I want to force the RDP session to display in **Portrait** mode only, regardless of the orientation of my Android phone.  My RDP session is established in Landscape mode and nothing I have done changes this.

What I've tried:

- Disabling (and enabling) auto-rotation in Android Settings.  Despite this setting, the RDP session *never* displays in Portrait mode, even if I rotate the phone
- Searched the Remote Desktop Client app for settings to control rotation
- Searched the Internet for appropriate terms.  I found [this post](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-updates-its-free-remote-desktop-apps-for-ios-mac-android-7000027397/) in which a commenter complains:

> The MS-ified version [of the RDP app] locks you into portrait mode.

So I am hopeful this is possible.

I am using a Cubot X6 phone running Android v4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft RDP android app didn't support portrait mode... but with your input on https://remotedesktop.uservoice.com/forums/272085-remote-desktop-for-android/suggestions/6851819-portrait-mode it finally got implemented:

> Our latest update to the app supports connecting in portrait mode. The
>   remote session adapts to your device orientation dynamically. You will
>   get the best experience using Windows 8.1 and newer.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is Ericom AccessToGo RDP
have both portrait full screen mode and barcode scan option

Comment: please add link from Play store as also briefly *which* feature of app meets OPs requirements

Answer (score -1):

There is the Microsoft Remote Desktop Beta app in the play store which supports both portrait mode and auto rotation.

Comment: Why the answer has been downvoted?